# Change in default Service host-port

Tags: quarkus

I'm upgrading a project that uses the kubernetes extension from quarkus 1.13 to 2.2.2.
The http Service generated in the kubernetes.yml went from using port 8080 to 80.  That however did not work on minikube for me when adding a loadbalancer to expose that service for testing (minikube expose service ...).  I was able to workaround by adding an override to the configuration:

quarkus.kubernetes.ports.http.host-port=8080

Is this an expected change in quarkus 2.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is expected the expected behavior for 2.0.
See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-2.0#service-port-mapping

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to look for that reference in the future.  Github and Google searches unfortunately weren't much help in trying to find to find why this was happening.

Comment: Yeah, this has been an issue. Github doesn't allow indexing of the wiki pages and we haven't done any work to copy the information to the website yet.